# Ruby on Rails - maximum count of associated objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, max

I need help with a query. I have multiple Canteens, where each has multiple Meals, where each meal has multiple MealPicks.

Although I don't know if this `MealPick` model is good idea, because I need to display how many times has the meal been picked TODAY, so I needed the timestamp to make this query.

```
class Meal < ActiveRecord::Base
  def todays_picks
    meal_picks.where(["created_at >= ? AND created_at < ?", Date.today.beginning_of_day, Date.today.end_of_day])
  end
end
```

Before I had just a meal_picked_count counter in Meal which I incremented by increment_counter method.

**Okay so, now I need to display for each Canteen the Meal that has the most MealPicks**, I played around in the console and tried something like `Canteen.find(1).meals.maximum("meal_picks.count")` but that obviously does not work as it is not a column.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
canteen.meals.max {|m| m.meal_picked_count}
```

Comment: I meanwhile made it work using sort_by {}.first, but this is better, thanks!

Comment: If each canteen has not so many meals, it will be efficient (due to an app logic). For potential unlimited records you should be better make it on a DB level and caching solutions.

Comment: yeah I read that, but performance is not an issue and its only like 50 meals per canteen

Comment: if your app logic has to preload these 50 meals anyway with each canteen, use 'max' iterator. But if not, make the caching solution. Load from DB 50 records just to determine maximum - bad news for performance. Although, if performance is not an issue...

Answer (score 7):

You can do this:

```
MealPick.joins(:meal => :canteen)
        .where("canteens.id = ?", 1)
        .order("count_all DESC")
        .group(:meal_id)
        .count
```

That will return an ordered hash like this:

```
{ 200 => 25 }
```

Where `200` would be the meal id and `25` would be the count.

***Update***

For anyone interested, I started playing around with this to see if I could use subqueries with ActiveRecord to give me meaningful information than what I came up with before.  Here's what I have:

```
class Meal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :canteen
  has_many :meal_picks
  attr_accessible :name, :price
  scope :with_grouped_picks, ->() {
    query = <<-QUERY
      INNER JOIN (#{Arel.sql(MealPick.counted_by_meal.to_sql)}) as top_picks 
      ON meals.id = top_picks.meal_id
    QUERY

    joins(query)
  }

  scope :top_picks, with_grouped_picks.order("top_picks.number_of_picks DESC")
  scope :top_pick, top_picks.limit(1)
end

class MealPick < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :meal
  attr_accessible :user

  scope :counted_by_meal, group(:meal_id).select("meal_id, count(*) as number_of_picks")
  scope :top_picks, counted_by_meal.order("number_of_picks DESC")
  scope :top_pick, counted_by_meal.order("number_of_picks DESC").limit(1)

end

class Canteen < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :meals
  has_many :meal_picks, through: :meals

  def top_picks
    @top_picks ||= meals.top_picks
  end

  def top_pick
    @top_pick ||= top_picks.first
  end
end
```

This allows me to do this:

```
c = Canteen.first
c.top_picks #Returns their meals ordered by the number of picks
c.top_pick  #Returns the one with the top number of picks
```

Let's say that I wanted to order all meals by the number of picks.  I could do this:

```
Meal.includes(:canteen).top_picks #Returns all meals for all canteens ordered by number of picks.
Meal.includes(:canteen).where("canteens.id = ?", some_id).top_picks #Top picks for a particular canteen
Meal.includes(:canteen).where("canteens.location = ?", some_location) #Return top picks for a canteens in a given location
```

Since we are using joins, grouping, and server-side counts, the whole collection need not be loaded to determine the pick count.  This is a bit more flexible and probably more efficient.

Comment: honestly that update is :fire: